# Why is my Angular interceptor not properly minified?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I have this interceptor:

```
angular.module('dwExceptionHandler', [])
    .factory('ExceptionInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(
                function (response) {
                    if (response && response.data.Exception) {
                        alert(response.data.Exception.Message);

                        return $q.reject(response);
                    }

                    return response;
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response.data.Exception) {
                        console.warn('ALERT', response.data.Exception.Message);
                        alert(response.data.Exception.Message.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'));
                    }

                    return $q.reject(response);
                });
        };
    }]).config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('ExceptionInterceptor');
    }]);
```

I am expecting an alert since I get an exception back from the server, but the alert isn't shown. It does show up in my development environment, where I don't use minification.

When I copy the minified part of the minified code it ooks like this:

```
angular.module("dwExceptionHandler",[]).factory("ExceptionInterceptor",["$q",function(n)
{
    return function(t){
        return t.then(function(t)
            {
                return 
                    t && t.data.Exception 
                        ? (alert(t.data.Exception.Message),n.reject(t))
                        : t
            },
            function(t)
            {
                return t.data.Exception 
                        && 
                        (   console.warn("ALERT",t.data.Exception.Message),
                            alert(t.data.Exception.Message.replace(/\\n/g,"\n"))),
                            n.reject(t)
            })
        }}])

        .config(["$httpProvider",function(n){n.responseInterceptors.push("ExceptionInterceptor")}]);
```

When I was studying this code I noticed that the `promise` and `response` variable both get the same variable assigned when minified: `t`.

How is this possible and how can I fix this? I use the .net Bundle config and I am not allowed to switch to grunt, gulp or use web essentials. I must stick with Bundle config.

Comment: You can add an `ng-strict-di` directive on the same element as `ng-app` to opt into strict DI mode.  You might consider trying this, and seeing what errors it generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though both variable names are the same, they're not actually using the same variable. The minifier was able to see that you don't use the `promise` variable inside your error callback, so it's okay for it to reuse the same variable name in the function's parameter. This effectively "hides" the other variable, making it inaccessible from within that function, but since you're not using the variable there, that doesn't matter.

In other words, the minification shouldn't be affecting your results. It appears to be valid, and you'll have to look elsewhere to figure out why you're not getting the desired behavior.

If you want to see the minified code using a different variable name, you could try to fool the minifier into thinking you're using the `promise` variable there, by adding a line like this into the callback method:

```
angular.noop(promise);
```